# Maven Update Error

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

I have newly created maven project with spring dependencies in the pom file, I have no idea what has happened with my project, I am getting this error while updating maven using Right Click > Maven > Update project :

[image]

Can somebody help me on this please.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy ?

Comment: Yes, I am, You mean to say it is because of proxy? How can we fix it ?

Comment: Chances are yes , Could not be sure w/o logs

Comment: Did you try to build your maven project on command line? If it builds successfully, I would suggest you to ask some Eclipse users because I guess it's an Eclipse related issue (add an eclipse tag to your question), or you just switch to NetBeans which is doing awesome together with maven ;)

Comment: You are right, it builds perfectly on the command line.